# How to unique value from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello guys i m new in php I have some multidimensional array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 100
            [user_id] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (

            [id] => 100
            [user_id] => 300
        )

    [2] => Array
        (

            [id] => 100
            [user_id] => 200
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 100
            [user_id] => 400
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 100
            [user_id] => 200
        )

)
```

I want to remove duplicate value like `array[0]` and `array[2]` and `array[4]` have. I mean i need my final output like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 100
            [user_id] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (

            [id] => 100
            [user_id] => 300
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 100
            [user_id] => 400
        )
)
```

Please help to i don't know to how to do in php.

Comment: If this is data retrieved from a database, then you'd be better ensuring that the database query didn't return duplicates in the first place

Comment: No its not from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: It's working fine check [**this**](https://eval.in/446203) +1

Comment: @Pupil you've done fine work but its the duplicate answer which the OP can get it from just using simple [**search**](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=array_unique+on+multidimensional+arrays&oq=array_unique+on+multi&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l3.9499j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: but waht if i have one more value in inside of array i mean like this  [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 100
            [user_id] => 400 
            [myvalue] => 4
        )